# Real Time Database in Azure - Listen to a table

Tags: c#, azure

How to create a listener (in the client) for a specific table in a database in Azure, like SQL Cloud. I've been looking in DB Cosmos, but it doesn't have this feature,it only contains change feeds.

Comment: How is change feed not meeting what you need when it's exactly that, a listener to a cosmos db collection which fires of a trigger on edited/new row. What challenge are you trying to solve?

Comment: I dont know, im too new in Azure enviroment. But for example. Client A create a product, i want to inmediatly reflects that product in Client B. is possible to make that with Change Feed with cosmo db?  or are another services for that specific case?

Comment: @DylanGrijalva what do you mean by client ? On the browser side ? if so use something like signalr / websocket ?

Comment: I mean, for example, suppose a mobile and/or web app displays remaining available quantity for a product in an online store. As users purchase the product, it is important to update the remaining quantity for all other users of the app.

Comment: Is there a way to do that in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you ask for is Azure Function Trigger for Cosmos DB:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function